# why does PHP fopen + fwrite double document?

Tags: php-5.3, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I am running PHP Version 5.3.4 with Apache/2.2.17 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit (IIS disabled).
I been looking at the [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) modes and am well aware of what mode does what, but i can't wrap my finger around why the double posting to the txt file with a single fwrite.
I've even tried modes: w and c.

Now I don't care whether the new data coming in is being prepend or appended, just so long as its there in the file without truncating existing data.

The real question is, why does the "a" mode instead of just appending new data, it writes (duplicates) the new data to the file twice before it closes.

In php code:

```
$fh = "";
if(!($fh = fopen("list.txt","x")) // if file exists, just open for writing (prepend)
   $fh = fopen("list.txt","a"); // if not exist, open just for writing (append)

fwrite($fh,"Somthing\r\n"); // write to file (filehandle, "data")
fclose($fh); // close the file
```

---

Results:
Somthing
Somthing

SOLVED:
Found the culprit: nothing was wrong with my coding. It was an [html validator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo) extension I used for Chromium under Ubuntu 10.04. This extension was apparently causing something similar to instant page reload.

Comment: you can use the "c" mode, which acts as "w" but doesn't wipe out the file. the double something seems like you ran the script twice.

Comment: Actually "c" mode seems to be truncating and writing new stuff. Each time i put new data in and load the php page, the old data is wiped in place of the new data.

Comment: INdeed, that was the problem. I never would have thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fh = fopen("list.txt","a");
fwrite($fh,"Somthing\n"); // write to file (filehandle, "data")
fclose($fh); // close the file
```

your logic was not correct.

that's how its done, i hope it works for you

Comment: sorry i fixed the little mistake, i had fopen x in both

Comment: I thought that the "x" mode will return false if the file exist? And it still double posts to the txt file.

Comment: actually you don't need to do a file exist, just do a `$fh = fopen("list.txt","a");` if the file doesn't exist it will create it, and if it does it will simply append the new data to it.

Comment: That was my initial approach was just using the "a" mode. I am baffled about the duplicate entry. If I output it to HTML, I only get one time, but in writing to file there is duplicate entries.

Comment: because with your aproach your are opening a handle twice so you are appending or writing twice. simply write this and give me feed back `$fh = fopen("list.txt","a");
fwrite($fh,"Somthing\n"); // write to file (filehandle, "data")
fclose($fh); // close the file
`

Comment: even as simple as those lines i still get double post into the file.

Comment: maybe you should look at some other part of your file, are you using redirects? or is there another condition for writing? provide more code maybe this is not the problem

Comment: no loop or nothing. just plain old $fh = fopen("list.txt","a");
fwrite($fh,"abc\r\n");
fclose($fh); @ http://robx.dyndns.info/app/fwrite.php all the links do is load the txt file and wipes content from the file. This page has no other codes, not even html. Just a straight php file with those simple few lines. Well, other than the links there's no other. I could strip everything but those, and you will see it double append every time you load the page.

Comment: um have you checked the link you just gave? it works!
you probably have a problem with your browser reloading or something. cause every time i reload the page i have one more line appended, isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Weird. I am using Chromium on Ubuntu. Wow, i think its actually a chrome problem. Maybe the browser is reloading itself for whatever reason. Tried it from smart device and it works just as well. thanks. What a headache.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this is years old but this problem is still known to occur and there is another reason that may also cause it.  I didn't have the extension used by @robx, disabled all my extensions and no change - still double entries.  However, after reading this thread about it being a Chrome bug (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810) comment 16 suggests the issue is the favicon being prefetched.  Not ideal but delete the favion icon link tag in the head of the document and it stops double entries.